# How to add line plot below heatmap with same x axis?

Tags: plotly

I am using plotly heatmap with x axis being date. Now I like to add a time line plot with same color axis of date below the heatmap such that the x axis of heatmap and line plot are aligned. How to do it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- create a figure to contain your traces
- add traces from heatmap and line figures to appropriate subplot
- align xaxis using `fig.update_traces(xaxis="x")`

```
import plotly.express as px
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    index=pd.date_range("1-jan-2022", periods=15),
    data={c: np.random.randint(1, 10, 15) for c in list("ABCD")},
)

fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1)
for t in px.imshow(df.values.T, x=df.index, y=df.columns).data:
    fig.add_trace(t, row=1, col=1)

for t in px.line(df, y=df.columns).data:
    fig.add_trace(t, row=2, col=1)

fig.update_traces(xaxis="x")
fig.update_layout(
    coloraxis_colorbar={"len": 0.5, "yanchor": "bottom"},
    legend={"yanchor": "top", "y": 0.5, "tracegroupgap": 0},
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Rob, sorry for late reply. I ran your code and got an error of 
TypeError: imshow() got an unexpected keyword argument 'x'. Thanks

Comment: plotly version? I'm using 5.5.0

Comment: I see, Rob my version is: 4.5.2

Comment: Rob, let me work on that more and I will accept it today

Comment: Thank you so much Rob, yes it works. one thinkg the colorbar of top heatmap cover whole graph area, how to limit colorbar to cover only its plot area which is top portion only? Thank you

Comment: updated to position colorbar and also legend if you want multiple line traces

Comment: Hi Rob, thank you! That is awesome. can you explain a little bit about what are 'len' and 'y', tracegroupgap in update_layout(), I tried to replicate it with my example, the position doesn't line up well.  Thank you!

Comment: Thank you Rob, sorry for more question, if I have defined layout for heatmap only using go.Layout(xaxis=,yaxis=) etc., where do I insert this go.layout? Thanks

Comment: `go.Layout()` details can be transposed as appropriate into the `fig.update_layout()` part